# Can I use the same power supply to double the voltage?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, battery-operated

I want to do a corded conversion as seen in this [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/18v-Makita-LXT-Power-Pack-Cordless-to-Corded-Conve/)
.  However, some Makita tools use dual batteries to have a 36V source.  That means the voltage from the 18V power supply will be combined to create a 36V source.  Will this present any problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the power supplies like in the link given in the question then you shouldn't combine the two of them to have 36 VDC. Because they will probably not be fully isolated (i.e. they share the safety ground line). Even if they were, it's not practical.

So, instead of picking an extra power supply, you may pick an adjustable/programmable power supply. This will be practical as it can be adequate for both type of devices, but will not be cheap as you might think.

Comment: Those 36V tools use 2x 18V batteries.  Since I am doing a cordless to corded conversion, that means 2x batteries with 18V coming from the same power supply.  I am wondering if there is any danger in this.

Comment: @CaTx: You do realize that using a single power supply means that you'll be connecting the positive supply directly to the negative supply, right?

Comment: @CaTx With cordless-to-corded conversion, you'll always be charging up the battery as well during the the operation of the tool. If you supply 18V to a 36V-tool then the power supply cannot charge the batteries since two 18V batteries are connected in series. I don't see any potential danger in this but keeping the 18V power supply connected to 36V-tool is meaningless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, how can I do a corded conversion for the 36V tool?  Use a 36V power supply and have a dual-battery setup?